# How to convert an array containing arrays of objects to single array witht hose object using Ramda expressions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping, ramda.js, flatten

I am having a difficult time, there is some bad mapping going on on my code.

I have an array containing array of objects like that :

```
[
   [{a: 1, b: 2},{a: 1, b: 3} ],
   [{a: 5, b: 2},{a: 2, b: 5}]
]
```

And I want to make like that :

```
[
   {a: 1, b: 2},
   {a: 1, b: 3},
   {a: 5, b: 2},
   {a: 2, b: 5}
]
```

In order to do that, I thought I found the magical solution, make things flat, using `flatten` function, it was not working ( this problem is just a piece of code in a lot of code ) and I was wondering why, i wasted some time to find that this the problem, it is not the behovior I am expecting, as you can see in the image, the first thing I have is an array containing an array having two objects, with `flatten` method, I was expecting an array of two objects, but I am getting what you see in the image :

[image]

The code I have ttried is this :

```
const expectedArray = R.flatten(myArrayOfArraysOfObjects);
```

Full example :

```
const singleTronconPoints = troncon => {
  return troncon.geometri_linestring;
};
console.log('troncons : ');
console.log(troncons);
console.log('map troncons points');
console.log(map(singleTronconPoints, troncons));
console.log('flatten');
console.log(flatten(map(singleTronconPoints, troncons)));
```

and this is full result : [image]

How can I solve that, is there another magical ( :P ) solution ( method ) to solve the problem ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] that shows the actual problem, because your [script parts work](https://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20input%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%5B%7Ba%3A%201%2C%20b%3A%202%7D%2C%7Ba%3A%201%2C%20b%3A%203%7D%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%5B%7Ba%3A%205%2C%20b%3A%202%7D%2C%7Ba%3A%202%2C%20b%3A%205%7D%5D%0A%5D%3B%0Aconst%20output%20%3D%20R.flatten%28input%29%3B%0Aconsole.log%28JSON.stringify%28output%29%29%3B)

Comment: then it must be not the flat method the problem, it must something else, because ramda flatten method is using flat already

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge/flatten an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays)

Answer (score 3):

[Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) can also be an option:

```
const arr =[
  [{a: 1, b: 2},{a: 1, b: 3}],
  [{a: 5, b: 2},{a: 2, b: 5}]
]

const expectedArray = arr.reduce((acc, array) => {
  acc.push(...array);
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: instead reduce + push ,flat()  or reduce + concat will work better.

Comment: You may go even furthermore code golfing: `arr.reduce((acc, array) => (acc.push(...array), acc))`. And that wasn't my downvote, by the way.

Comment: @VijayPalaskar : would you share some relevant benchmarks to back that statement? Just in case, [mine](https://jsbench.me/0ikcqa83ck/1) shows different

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov thanks for pointing out .It will very helpful for me. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array.flat`

```js
let a = [
  [{
    a: 1,
    b: 2
  }, {
    a: 1,
    b: 3
  }],
  [{
    a: 5,
    b: 2
  }, {
    a: 2,
    b: 5
  }]
];

let b = a.flat();
console.log(b)
```

Alternatively you can use `reduce` and inside callback use `forEach` and puch items from the nested array to accumulator array

```js
let a = [
  [{
    a: 1,
    b: 2
  }, {
    a: 1,
    b: 3
  }],
  [{
    a: 5,
    b: 2
  }, {
    a: 2,
    b: 5
  }]
];

let b = a.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  curr.forEach(item => acc.push(item))
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(b)
```

Comment: `acc.push(...curr)` is shorthand for `curr.forEach(item => acc.push(item))`

Answer (score 2):

use  [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) + push which faster [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method.

**refer this for to check performance.** : https://jsbench.me/0ikcqa83ck/1

```js
let arr = [
           [{a: 1, b: 2},{a: 1, b: 3} ],
           [{a: 5, b: 2},{a: 2, b: 5}]
        ]

      console.log(arr.flat())
        
        let flattenArr = arr.reduce((acc, val) => (acc.push(...val),acc), [])
        console.log(flattenArr);
```

Comment: If you care about performance do not use the spread operator.

Comment: This perform faster than flat & reduce+ concat .

Answer (score 1):

[Array.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) is the magical solution you are looking for !

```js
var arr = [
   [{a: 1, b: 2},{a: 1, b: 3} ],
   [{a: 5, b: 2},{a: 2, b: 5}]
]

console.log(arr.flat())
```